# Location services not working in ios8

Tags: ios, ios8, cllocationmanager

I'm struggling for a couple of days now and I'm not able to solve my problem (despite all info here on SO). Sorry for being stupid.

In my app location services stopped working in iOS 8. Prior to this version all was OK.
I read here that there must me some keys in de plist file and that they must be set using a external editor.

Here it is:
[image: Screenshot of keys in Plist file]

But it is still not working. In the simulator, or on my device for that matter, I am not be prompted.

I also understand to add some code to my files.
What code should I add, where should I add it?

This is my .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *location;
```

This is in my .m file:

```
@synthesize location;

-(void) locationStuff {

//Get location en set MapView

location=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
location.delegate=self;
location.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
location.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
location.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

[self startUpdatingLocation];

[mapView setDelegate:self];
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"appRunning"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

}

Can, please, anyone help me? Thanks and again sorry that I didn't understand the answers provided to the other questions. I really need some simple explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has changed in iOS 8, You have to request  for location servive with following code.

- `requestAlwaysAuthorization` -  for background location

  `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];`or
- `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`-location only when app is active

  `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`

If you do not make either of two request , iOS will ignore startUpdateLocation request.

Also.
Include `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key , Which i see you have already Done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a partly. I put the code [self.location requestAlwaysAuthorization]; in my viewDidLoad. Sometimes the dialog pops up and sumetimes not. The keys are still in the same place. Sometimes it comes up with a location and my app works and sometimes there is no location visible and obviously the app is not working. Any suggestions?